# ElasticSearch: How can I get all child objects of different types using parent/child inner hits

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a problem with "inner hits" feature. I can get only one type of child objects, because [I have to specify](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.1/search-request-inner-hits.html#parent-child-inner-hits) the type of child objects for the query.

For example, I can successfully get all parent objects and their "ChildA" objects using the following code

```
{
  "query": {
    "has_child": {
      "type": "ChildA",
      "query": {
        "match_all": {}
      },
      "inner_hits": {}
    }
  }
}
```

Is it possible to get ChildA and ChildB objects simultaneously?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can combine multiple `has_child` queries with `inner_hits` using a `bool` query. For example, if you wanted to find all the parents that had either a "ChildA" or a "ChildB" and then return all the children that they have (whether ChildA or ChildB or both), you could do something like this:

```
"query": {
  "bool": {
    "should": [
      {
        "has_child": {
          "type": "ChildA",
          "query": {
            "match_all": {}
          },
          "inner_hits": {}
        }
      },
      {
        "has_child": {
          "type": "ChildB",
          "query": {
            "match_all": {}
          },
          "inner_hits": {}
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```